# Статусы клиента и их история

Tags: 1с

Всем привет, коллеги.
Дело в следующем. Неободимо реализовать функционал, где для каждого покупателя должна вестись история его статусов. Возможные статусы: Новый клиент, Постоянный клиент, Ключевой клиент; Потерянный клиент.
Статусы могут менять ся со временем.
Всю историю статусов нужно видеть из карточки клиента. + Нужна возможность тут же из карточки изменить статус
В форме списка контрагентов вывести колонки: Название / текущий Статус

Не могу понять алгоритм реализации.
Я создал регистр сведений, перечисления со статусами. Добавил в карточку справочника Контрагенты реквизит статусов.

Но как записывать сведения в регистр из карточки справочника понять не могу.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

№1

> Всю историю статусов нужно видеть из карточки клиента

Установи у измерения регистра, хранящего ссылку на контрагента, свойство "Ведущее".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда у тебя автоматически платформа будет выводить гиперссылку в панели навигации формы.

Книга **Разработка интерфейса прикладных решений на платформе "1С:Предприятие 8"** - [Глава 2.6. Командный интерфейс окна клиентского приложения](https://its.1c.ru/db/pubv8devui#content:135:hdoc)

№2

> Нужна возможность тут же из карточки изменить статус

Тебе нужен обработчик элемента "ПриИзменении()". В нем пишешь код, который будет менять данные в регистре.

№3

> Добавил в карточку справочника Контрагенты реквизит статусов

Это излишне. Ты же статус хранишь в регистре сведений. Создай реквизит формы, и заполняй его при открытии элемента данными из регистра.

№4

> Но как записывать сведения в регистр из карточки справочника понять не могу

Изучай программную работу с регистром сведений:

- [Работа с регистрами сведений в 1С 8.3 и 8.2](https://programmist1s.ru/registryi-svedeniy-1s/)
- [Программная работа с регистрами сведений](https://pro1c8.ru/programmnaya-rabota-registr-svedenij/)
- [Регистры сведений в языке 1С 8.3, 8.2 (в примерах)](https://helpme1s.ru/registry-svedenij-v-yazyke-1s-8-v-primerax)